# Removing falsies from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object, delete-operator

So I write a short function to remove members from an object that have falsy values:

```
for (var key in object) {
    if (!object[key]) {
        delete object[key];
    }
}
```

A couple days later I check source control and someone has changed this to:

```
var newObject = {};
for (var key in object) {
    if (object[key]) { newObject[key] = object[key]; }
}
return newObject;
```

There's no comments on the check-in and the guy is not here today at work.

Which implementation is better? What are the performance implications of each method?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot delete a property on an object that it inherits from a prototype. So in some cases your code may fail to work as expected.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `delete` a property of an object that it inherits from a `prototype` (although you can delete it directly on the prototype).

In the second example, a falsy property inherited from a `prototype` will not be copied to the `newObject`.

Further reading:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: delete Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/), consider this implementation (using [_.pick](http://lodash.com/docs#pick)):

```
var newObject = _.pick(object, function onlyTruthy(val, key) {
  return !!val;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code reads much more intuitively. Maybe he just didn't want to change the original object?

Comment: Not true, see Daniel's and Yacoby's answers.

Comment: Those answers and mine are not mutually exclusive. Well, at least they may not be. We don't have enough context to make a determination.